# Google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to enter data generated by a script other than `sheet.appendRow(rowContents)`?

I would like to enter new data into specific spreadsheet cells.

Please excuse my ignorance if this is really a DUMB question and Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way which reverses the process of getting values from a spreadsheet.

```
    function writeData(){

       var  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
       var new1=sheet.getRange("B3:D3");
       var new2=new1.getValues();
       new2[0][0]=21;
       new2[0][1]="extra";
       new2[0][2]=48.3
       new1.setValues(new2);
       new1.copyValuesToRange(0,2,4,3,3);
       }
```